# How do I delete and update a photo in Laravel 4?

Tags: php, mysql, file-upload, laravel-4

In my application, a user can upload an image for their profile photo. How do I update a users photo and the delete the previously uploaded photo? This is what I have so far in the upload controller:

**Photos Model**

```
class Photos extends Eloquent {


    protected  $table = 'photos';

    protected $fillable = array('user_id', 'location');

    public  function user (){

        return $this->belongsTo('User');
    }





}
```

**user model**

```
public function photos()
{
    return $this->hasOne('photos');
}
```

**Upload Controller**

```
class UploadController extends \BaseController {

public function postUpload (){

    $id = Auth::user()->id;

    $input = Input::all();

    $rules = array(
        'photo' => 'required|image|max:500'
    );


    $validator = Validator::make($input, $rules);

    if($validator->fails()){
        return Redirect::to('user/profile/'.$id.'/edit')->withErrors($validator);
    }

    $extension = Input::file('photo')->getClientOriginalExtension();
    $directory =  public_path('/var/chroot/home/content/59/11581559/html/beta') . '/uploads/'.sha1($id);

    $filename = sha1($id.time()).".{$extension}";
    $upload_success = Input::file('photo')->move($directory, $filename);

    Image::make(Input::file('photo')->getRealPath())->resize(300, 200)->save('foo.jpg');

    if($upload_success){

        $photo = new Photos(array(
            'location' => URL::to('/uploads/'.sha1($id).'/'.$filename)
        ));

        $photo->user_id = $id;
        $photo->save();

        Session::flash('success_photo', 'You have Successfully uploaded your profile photo!');
        return Redirect::to('user/profile/'.$id.'/edit');
    }
    else{
        Session::flash('status_error', 'An Error has occurred while uploading your photo. Please try again!');
    }

    return Redirect::to('user/profile/'.$id.'/edit');

    }
}
```

**View**

```
    <div class="col-lg-3">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">



                @if(Session::has('status_error'))
                <div class="alert alert-error">
                    <a class="close" data-dismiss="alert" href="#" aria-hidden="true">&times;</a>
                    {{ implode('', $errors->all('<li class="error"><b>:status_error</b></li>')) }}
                </div>
                @endif

                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-exclamation-sign"></span> Upload a Photo

            </div>

            <div class="panel-body text-center">

                @if($user->photos)
                    <img width="190" height="119" class="img-responsive img-thumbnail" src="{{$user->photos->location }}" alt="">
                @endif
                <div class="clearfix"></div>
                <div class="btn-group mtop-20">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="$('#upload_modal').modal({backdrop:'static'});">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-upload"></span>
                    </button>
                </div>

            </div>


            <?php echo View::make('modals.photo-upload') ?>
    </div><!-- end panel-default -->
</div><!-- col 3-->
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's talk about what you're doing and work from there.

**Uploading a Photo**
 -  In your controller, you're uploading a photo.
 -  If the upload succeeds, you're storing the location of the photo on your server as well as the ID of the user to whom the photo belongs.

**Updating a Photo**
 -  In your controller, you're uploading a photo.
 -  If the upload succeeds, you're going to:

- Get the location of the current file in the database.

  `$this->photo->where('user_id' , '=' , $the_user_id_in_question)
                 ->get(array('location'));`
- Delete the file at that location using the `delete()` function in the FileSystem class (found here: https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/master/src/Illuminate/Filesystem/Filesystem.php)
- Update the user's photo location with the new one:

  `$this->photo->where('user_id' , '=' , $the_user_id_in_question)
             ->update('location' => $the_new_upload_location);`

I hope that's what you're looking for.  Cheers!